# Button is not displaying at all

Tags: xml, eclipse, android-layout, xml-parsing

I am working on android as a beginner. I was trying to display "Go" button just after the EditText but it does not display on activity. I have following code to display the button in my xml file.
What should i do now ?
Please Help

Xml File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/loc"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:ems="10">
        <requestFocus />
</EditText>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
         android:text="@string/go"
         android:onClick="geoLocate"/>


     </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you
Change your Inner `EditText` to

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/loc"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
     <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ems="10">
        <requestFocus />
     </EditText>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
         android:text="@string/go"
         android:onClick="geoLocate"/>


     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx buddy. It worked for me. I will like to rate this answer . But before you tell what was the actual problem and why u suggested some things to add/change ?